# UPDATE DB SET ... fills ONE specific VARCHAR with 0 or 1, regardless of the value I set

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I am running the following query, via php mysqli `$con->query($sql);`

PHP code:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE registrations SET '.$update_columns_list.' WHERE registrationkey = "'.$registration['RegistrationKey'].'"';
echo "RESULT: ".$result = $con->query($sql);
```

Value of `$sql` in above example:

```
UPDATE registrations SET referenceid = "4469731" and action = "newregistration" and status = "newregistration" and registrationdatetimegmt = "1363371386" and billingmonth = "2013-03" and accessexpirationdatetimegmt = "1373957999" and returnurl = "https://api.mywebsite.com/login.aspx?siteid=209" and lastmodifieddatetimegmt = "1363371398" and studentkey = "12345-67890-12345-67890" and firstname = "amanda" and lastname = "hemingway" and email = "amandamhemingway@trashymail.com" and phonenumber = "111-111-1111" and city = "city" and state = "ca" and postalcode = "90210" and country = "us" and coursecode = "ABC-406" and coursetitle = "example course title" and courseproductcode = "t3310" WHERE registrationkey = "12345-67890-12345-67890"
```

Everything seems fine when I run this query (I get a "success" message and the affected row count is just as expected). However, when I look at the affected row in the database via phpMyAdmin, where I continually find either 1 or 0 values in the 'referenceid' column. There are no other scripts affecting this table or database. I have been unable to determine any pattern as to when it places a 0 instead of a 1.

Both `referenceid` and `keyid` fields are `VARCHAR(100)`'s.

Comment: is that the full update statement you are executing?

Comment: what is the php code with the query in it?

Comment: Try commas instead of `and`

Comment: replace your `and`s with `,`

Comment: Thanks, Waygood. This fixed the issue. I saw your comment after I replied to J W's answer below.

Comment: btw avoid mysql, it is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated question to display the correct method for newer versions.

Comment: Why do people keep writing answers as comments? Grrrrr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update statement you are executing performs boolean operation. It's a behaviour in mysql that I don't like.

The current update statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE tableName SET col1 = 2 AND col2 = 3
```

and `MySQL` server doesn't throw any exceptions because the syntax is permitted and it reads it as:

```
UPDATE tableName SET col1 = (2 AND (col2 = 3))
```

If you want to update multiple columns, use `,` to separate the column not `AND`.

```
UPDATE registrations 
SET    referenceid = "4469731",
       action = "newregistration", .....
```

Comment: Thanks! The logic flaw that caused my original problem is much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

When you update you don't add columns with and, rather than with a comma, so your Update should look like:

```
UPDATE registrations 
 SET referenceid = "4469731",
     action = "newregistration",
     status = "newregistration",
     registrationdatetimegmt = "1363371386",
     billingmonth = "2013-03",
     accessexpirationdatetimegmt = "1373957999",
     returnurl = "https://api.mywebsite.com/login.aspx?siteid=209",
     lastmodifieddatetimegmt = "1363371398",
     studentkey = "12345-67890-12345-67890",
     firstname = "amanda",
     lastname = "hemingway",
     email = "amandamhemingway@trashymail.com",
     phonenumber = "111-111-1111",
     city = "city",
     state = "ca",
     postalcode = "90210",
     country = "us",
     coursecode = "ABC-406",
     coursetitle = "example course title",
     courseproductcode = "t3310"
 WHERE registrationkey = "12345-67890-12345-67890"
```